# Google Apps Script Duplicate A File

Tags: file, google-apps-script, duplicates

I am simply trying to duplicate an open sheets file. I tried so many variation without success. The below is an example. Would value any assistance. Thank You.

```
function copyDocs() {
    var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('My Income Statement');
    file.makeCopy();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Data retrieved using `DriveApp.getFilesByName()` is [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator). In this case, file is retrieved by using `next()`.

There are 2 patterns for the sample script.

### Sample script 1

#### Pattern 1 :

If the filename is only one in your Drive, you can use following sample script. This sample copies the file using the filename.

```
function copyDocs() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('My Income Statement').next();
  file.makeCopy();
}
```

#### Pattern 2 :

If there are files with the same filename and you want to copy one of them, you can use following sample script. This sample copies the file using the fileID. The fileID can be retrieved as follows.

For document,

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/### File ID ###/edit
```

For spreadsheet,

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/### File ID ###/edit
```

Sample script :

```
function copyDocs() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("### File ID ###");
  file.makeCopy();
}
```

### Sample script 2

This sample is for opening the copied file using a dialog on spreadsheet. Since the copied file is opened as new window, please permit to open popup window.

1. Copy and paste following script to container-bound script of spreadsheet.
2. Run `dialog()`.
3. Push a copy button on the dialog box on spreadsheet.

By above flow, the file with `fileId` is copied and opened as new window.

```
function dialog() {
  var data = '<input type="button" value="copy" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(openfile).filecopy();"><script>function openfile(url) {window.open(url);}</script>';
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(data);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Sample dialog');
}

function filecopy(){
  var fileId = "### File ID ###";
  return DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy().getUrl();
}
```

Comment: Thank You, Tanaike! I very much am grateful for the code and it worked perfectly. The only remaining issue is that once the file is copied, I would like to immediately open the file - would you please be able to assist?

Comment: If you want to open the copied file after it was copied using google apps script, you can do it using menus and dialogs. You can see the detail information [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui).

Comment: Thank You, Tanaike. I am a novice to Google Apps Script - I reviewed the link but I am afraid I am not certain how to proceed . . .I didn't note any script for opening a file . . . would appreciate any suggestions to start if you are inclined . . .thank you.

Comment: @Tacitus I added a sample script as "Sample script 2". Please check it. The sample is for opening the copied file using a dialog on spreadsheet. If you don't want the method, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank You, Tanaike for your generous help! I will practice with the code you posted!

Comment: it can be useful to note that makeCopy accepts arguments https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy%28String,Folder%29 (name and destination, that can be used to open or work with the file afterwards in a script).