# Google Script, temporary sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script in google scripts where I set up an HTML with some , the user fills them in, and the data goes to a google spreadsheet, then I get the spreadsheet link and add "export?format=pdf" at the end to download the pdf for the user.
My problem is that many people will use this application, is there any way to make a temporary copy for each user who is going to edit it? on google driver for example

Comment: This should be doable, see [Tanaike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095087/google-apps-script-duplicate-a-file). Just make sure to delete it before your script ends.

Comment: thank you it was almost what was necessary, i managed to adapt, vlw